# .net application cannot connect to DB2 DataBase

Tags: .net, db2

ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected.  Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "10.66.180.30".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download the driver directly from the IBM page ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons for this error, your db2 is started? oyou have configured the node, the runtime client is properly installed?, check out this [link](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?q1=SQL30081N&rs=71&uid=swg21164785&context=SSEPGG&cs=utf-8&lang=en&loc=en_US) for more.

Comment: hi the link redirects to error code SQL30081N. But the error code above is SQL30081N A. This is the correct [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21499220)

Comment: hm maybe it is SQL30081N.. but the link I provided is also an official IBM page about this error code.

Comment: [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164785)"These error messages are returned when DB2 calls operating system socket APIs that receive an error message from a component outside of DB2. These socket errors are propagated back up to DB2 which encapsulates the error inside the SQL30081N message." [details](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30081n.html)