# IBM DB2 Connection using VS2012 framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, db2, database-connection, ibm-midrange

I am trying to connect to IBM DB2 using VS2012 and framework 4.0. 
I installed the 64 bit IBM Data Server Driver Package (DS Driver) (V10.5 fix pack 2) and 32 bit (only 1 available) IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio (V10.1 FP 2)

If I connect using ODBC drivers, the connection is successful. But if I use IBM.Data.DB2 to connect, I get the following error:

> ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been
>   detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication
>   API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected:
>   "10.60.20.34".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".
>   Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

Here is the sample code:

```
string connStr = "Database=TestDB;User ID=demouser;Password=demouser5;Server=DemoServer;Connection Timeout=0";
DB2Connection cn = new DB2Connection();

cn.ConnectionString = connStr;
cn.Open();

Console.ReadKey();
cn.Close();
```

[This link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21503305) says that it might be a firewall problem on the server, but then how is ODBC able to connect and IBM drivers throws an exception.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully this can help get you somewhere - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762206/net-application-cannot-connect-to-db2-database?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure the configuration for ODBC is the same as in the framework? Do you have a 'data server client' installed? is it correctly configured? have you tried an attach to a remote instance? have you test the telnet check by giving the DB2 port?

Comment: @AngocA : I found out that our database is **UDB2** running on AS400. A connection cannot be made using _IBM.Data.DB2_ to it. I had to use **IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries** for this and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'll put some additional information here that may help, now that you know what you are connecting to.

Basically, there are three members of the DB2 family.  Which one you use depends on the operating system:  IBM z/OS, IBM i, or LUW [Linux/Unix/Windows].  For the most part, they have largely the same basic features, but there are subtle and not so subtle differences.

We don't actually have AS/400's anymore, though some people still call them that.  If your system is recent and up to date, then you are probably using **IBM i 7.1** (the OS) on a **Power 7 System** (the hardware).  Some systems are still on IBM i 6.1, or even i5/OS v5r4.

DB2 is a tightly integrated and inseparable component of the OS, so your version of DB2 is the version of the OS.

Be sure to use the appropriate version of the [**IBM i Information Center**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/eserver/ibmi.html) for your SQL reference.  Do not make the mistake of using the sites for DB2 LUW or DB2 z/OS.

- [IBM i 7.1 SQL Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintro.htm)
- [IBM i 6.1 SQL Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzintro.htm)
- [i5/OS v5r4 SQL Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzmst02.htm)

The connectivity software you are most likely using is [**IBM i Access for Windows**](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_resources.html), which includes a .NET Data Provider to use with DB2 for i.  You will want the version matching the IBM i OS version, or higher, but not lower.  Make sure that you have the latest service pack installed for your version.

You may want to review [connection string parameters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Fconnectkeywords.htm).  Your system manager (or DBA *if* there is one for the system) may be able to recommend proper settings.

I suggest using "system naming" in order to take advantage of the "library list", which allows DB2 to search through various schemas ("libraries") when you do not qualify a table or view with the schema name, somewhat akin to a Windows PATH environment variable.  We tend to prefer this method, which makes code more flexible across various environments.

*PS.  The [ibm-midrange](/questions/tagged/ibm-midrange) will apply to your questions on this site.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the default port for connectivity under Server info. It is `446`. So your connectionString would look like

```
string connStr = "Database=TestDB;User ID=demouser;Password=demouser5;Server=DemoServer:446;Connection Timeout=0";
```

Please note you would need a valid `DB2 Connect` license in order to an connect to ISeries.